# How to determine FTDI driver installed in clickonce application?

Tags: clickonce

I produced a C# application which needs FTDI driver be installed. I deployed my application with clickonce. How I determine the FTDI driver is installed in prerequisites (in Product.xml file)?

Comment: Are you aware that Clickonce cannot install drivers?

Comment: FTDI driver has an installer. I put this installer in prerequisites of clickonce deployment. That installer works fine. But if FTDI driver already installed in computer, it install again. How I prevent reinstallation of the driver in Product.xml file?